# While uploading the HTML file reading the image tag and fetching its dimension in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here I'm uploading an HTML file. This HTML file contains an `<img>` tag.
E.G.:

```
<img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">
```

It should read the image tag i.e `<img>` and tell respective image tag height and width i.e dimension

https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/#toc-reading-files

This is the link I followed for reading the content.

```
// HTML
<input type="file" id="files" name="file" />

// JavaScript
function readBlob(start, stop) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    // If we use onloadend, we need to check the readyState.
    reader.onloadend = function (evt) {
        if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) { // DONE == 2
            document.getElementById('byte_content').textContent = evt.target.result;
            document.getElementById('byte_range').textContent =
                    ['Read bytes: ', start + 1, ' - ', stop + 1,
                        ' of ', file.size, ' byte file'].join('');
        }
    };
    var blob = file.slice(start, stop + 1);
    reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
}

var file = document.getElementById('files');

document.querySelector('.readBytesButtons').addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
    if (evt.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'button') {
        var startByte = evt.target.getAttribute('data-startbyte');
        var endByte = evt.target.getAttribute('data-endbyte');
        readBlob(startByte, endByte);
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JS - File Reader API get image file size and dimensions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17773998/js-file-reader-api-get-image-file-size-and-dimensions)

Comment: No i checked the link. Here im uploading the HTML file . In html file it contain image tag. It should read the image tag and tell respective image tag height and width i.e dimension